# click event not working when i show 25 record per page in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have an issue with the datatable jQuery plugin. When my datatable loads, by default pre page value is 10, but after that I change to 25 records per page. So after the 10th record, click events don't work.

I use this code for the click event:

```
function driverClickable(){  $('#tabletest tbody tr').click(function() {
//setDriverEvents();
var data = $(this).html();
//console.log(data);
var find = '<td>';
var find2 = '</td>';
var find3 = '<td class="sorting_1">';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
var re2 = new RegExp(find2, 'g');
var re3 = new RegExp(find3, 'g');
data = data.replace(re, ',');
data = data.replace(re2, '');
data = data.replace(re3, '');    
ViewDriver(data);    }); }

function setDriverEvents(){  driverClickable();
 $('#tabletest').on( 'page.dt', function () {
setTimeout(function(){
  driverClickable();
}, 500);   });}
```

and this is my code to add data into the datatable

```
tableDriverData = $('#tabletest').dataTable({
        "data": driverData,
    });
```

What is the proper solution for this issue?

Comment: Use event delegation. The plugin changes the DOM so not all rows exist when your code runs

Comment: Try "length.dt" event or "draw.dt" event. The first event is when page length is modified and the second when the render is done.

Comment: can you give me example please so i can change into my code

Comment: @TrusharNarodia

$('#dataTable').on('length.dt', function () {
                    //your logic goes here
                    let noOfRecordsPage = $(element).DataTable().page.len();
                });

Answer (score 1):

> **CAUSE**

DataTables removes non-visible rows from DOM for various reasons so when you attach an event handler it works for currently visible elements only.

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use event delegation by providing selector as a second argument in [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call.

```
$('#tabletest tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
   // ... skipped ...
});
```

> **LINKS**

See [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.